# How to call an Activity from a Preference Activity?

Tags: android, preference

I would like to know how I can start an Activity from a Preference Activity.
My Scenario is like :

I have an application which display a set of images in a View. It can be GridView, or a Gallery View or a ListView.(The default view will be GridView)

On Pressing Menu, i ll get a preference Menu where i have List Preference of views (GridView/GalleryView/ListView).

On selecting a Particular View my main Activity's View which displays images should change.
I would like to know how i can implement this?

I thought of calling my main Activity by an intent which will be invoked on clicking a view in the preference Activity.

Is that possible?

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Write a `PreferenceActivity`.

Step #2: Have your main activity reload the preference in `onResume()` and update its UI accordingly.

You do not need to "call an Activity from a Preference Activity?". Your original activity will regain the foreground once the user presses BACK to exit from the `PreferenceActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

Call the Activity from Preference activity  should be like this.

```
Preference  prefereces=findPreference("key");
 prefereces.setIntent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class));
```